# Reinstalling grub2 from an ubuntu live usb

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, live-usb

I've installed FreeBsd along with Arch and Windows in place of Ubuntu. So initially I had Ubuntu, Arch and Windows.

I did something wrong and now it boots in grub menu. I've created a live ubuntu usb and booted from it. I ran Boot-repair and it eventually poped up a box requiesting to do:

```
"sudo chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda5"
"pacman -R grub*-common grub-common:i386 shim-signed- linux-signed"
```

I did so but the 2nd command returned an error saying "target grub*-common" not found, as well as other targets. I pressed OK in Boot-Repair but it said "Grub is still present, try again".

Pacman itself worked well.

What's up with it? How can I reinstall grub2 from an ubuntu live usb in my case?

Comment: I don't really see why you should be removing grub as opposed to simply fixing it. Try the steps described [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109492/22222), does that fix your issue?